# setHighlighted not working properly when I need to fill cells from Array

Tags: ios, swift

I have made a custom table view cell where I am overriding the setHighlighted function as per below.

```
override func setHighlighted(_ highlighted: Bool, animated: Bool) {
    let color = self.shadowView.backgroundColor
    super.setHighlighted(highlighted, animated: animated)
    if highlighted == true {
        self.shadowView.backgroundColor = .lightGray
    } else {
        self.shadowView.backgroundColor = color
    }
}
```

The problem is that self.shadowView.backgroundColor all background colors for each cell are filled up from Array of colors. And when I launch the app colors are correct but when I press on any cell it is highlighted but it seems that  tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true) never gets called.

But when I am simply using one color for each cell like this:

```
override func setHighlighted(_ highlighted: Bool, animated: Bool) {
    super.setHighlighted(highlighted, animated: animated)
    if highlighted == true {
        self.shadowView.backgroundColor = .lightGray
    } else {
        self.shadowView.backgroundColor = .blue
    }
}
```

Then everything works perfectly and cell gets deselected.

Maybe somebody already faced such issue?

Comment: what is `shadowView.backgroundColor` and what is it's background color?

Comment: shadowView.background color is filled like this: cell.shadowView.backgroundColor = Helper().hexStringToUIColor(hex: tableViewCellColors[indexPath.section]) and color array is this let tableViewCellColors = ["#ff7979", "#badc58", "#f9ca24", "#f0932b", "#eb4d4b", "#6ab04c", "#e056fd"]

Comment: is this a simple typo, where you want to set `self.shadowView.backgroundColor` to `.lightGray` if highlighted is `false` (instead of `true`, how you have it right now)??

Comment: I don't understand... The logic is that if I cell is highlighted (highlighted == true) then I am setting background to .lightGrey but if it is not true then color from tableViewCellColors should be used.

Comment: If `highlighted == false`, then you're setting the shadow view's background color to its own background color, i.e. no change happens. Could this be the problem?

Comment: After setting the shadow view's background color to `.lightGray` for the first time, it will always remain light gray, since its background color is essentially set to itself on subsequent calls.

Comment: then how to deselect the cell to the actual background color?

Comment: Write `tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)` in  `didSelectRowAt` method. It'll deSelect the cell.

Comment: Already did it, it does not work.

Comment: And commet the `setHighlighted ` method

Comment: I added setHighlihted method for a reason, because my table view cell is custom made with rounded corners etc so in order to highlight cell properly(with rounded corners) and to show shadows I have to use setHighlighted.